# "TypeError:_new_() take at least 2 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python

I try to create the program generate the linear programming problem like

```
min cx
s.t. Ax=b
x>=0
```

but it occur the problem the program warn the message

> ```
> "File"/tmp/tmpgX7_hI/___code___.py", line 3, in <module> class LP:"
> "File"/tmp/tmpgX7_hI/___code___.py", line 4, in LP c=matrix()"
> "TypeError: _new_() take at least 2 arguments (1 given)"
> ```

Which is my mistake and how should i fix it?
Please!!!

```
Program
    class LP:
        c=matrix()
        A=matrix()
        b=matrix()
        def__init__(self,cvector,Amatrix,bvector):
            self.c=cvector
            self.A=Amatrix
            self.b=bvector
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    import random 
    colc=[]colAmatrix=[]
    colb=[]
    LP_GEN=[]
    for m in range(2,5):
        for n in range(2,5):
            for k in range(2):
                c=matrix(1,n)
                for i in range(n):
                c[0,i]=random.randint(-50,50)
                b[0,i]=random.randint(-50,50)
                A[0,i]=random.randint(-50,50)
LP_GEN.append(LP(c,A,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you are creating the instances of the `matrix` class.
You're doing this:

```
c=matrix()
```

But it should be something like:

```
c=matrix(ARGUMENTS_HERE)
```

depending on the required arguments to create `matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

In your class definition, you use `matrix()`. But you have to pass at least one data to it. I think you may want:

```
class LP:
    def__init__(self,cvector,Amatrix,bvector):
        self.c=matrix(cvector)
        self.A=matrix(Amatrix)
        self.b=matrix(bvector)
```

Where `cvector`, `Amatrix`, `bvector` should be an array or a string. By the way, `matrix(1, n)` will also lead to an error.

Comment: I follow for you suggest but it is not effective.
The program warn me "data type not understood"

Comment: Where is the warning? You could edit your question for the new problem.